# Prevent UIScrollView from cancelling touchesMoved: of subview?

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, xamarin.ios

I have a `UIScrollView`. On top of it I allow the user to add a `DraggableView` (a subclass of `UIImageView`) by applying a long press gesture to the `UIScrollView`.
The `DraggableView` overrides `touchesMoved:` and allows the user to drag the view around.
This works until either one of two cases happens:

- The `UIScrollView` detects another long press while the user moves (after all his finger has been on the screen for a while)
- The `UIScrollView` starts to scroll.

What is the best way to prevent the long press detection and the scrolling of the scroll view while the user is dragging my view around? Is there a built in mechanism or do I have to keep track of a status somewhere and react accordingly?

Replies in ObjC and Monotouch are both welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out meanwhile. UIScrollView has a property do enable or disable scrolling. I just set that and enable scrolling again once my long press has been handled.